# An regex to extract SQL where clause

Tags: sql, regex, parsing, where-clause, conditional-statements

First, I confess I'm not realy experimented with regular expressions. I know how use it but when I want to build one, it's something else... I'm going to document me.

I want to extract the WHERE clause in a SQL query. My goal is to be able to add an condition, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTbl WHERE columnA = 'B' AND columnB = 'C' ORDER BY columnX GROUP BY columnZ LIMIT 5
```

TO :

```
SELECT * FROM myTbl WHERE columnC = 'D' AND (columnA = 'B' AND columnB = 'C') ORDER BY columnX GROUP BY columnZ LIMIT 5
```

I tried some expression but I'm so void...

```
(where (.*)(?<=order by))
```

I wanted to get all between 'where' and ('order by' or 'limit' or 'group by')...

Anyone have an advice for me ? I have done some search and I don't find anything like this. I found SQL Parser but these engines are too big compared to the task I want to complete.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how generic you need this, but do you need to be wary of more than one where clause, e.g. in a subquery?

Comment: I have similar problem and closest I could get is with this expression:
(?:^|\))(?:[^\(\)]+)(?:where\s+)(.*?)(?:group by|order by|$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `WHERE` clause can be quite complex (including subqueries which may include an `ORDER BY` in some cases, for instance when used with `FOR XML`), so you will not be able to really find an always reliably working solution with a regex.

A better solution would be to use a proper SQL parser which generates an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), and then you can just extract the `WHERE` clause from that. For T-SQL, you could use the parser from the [bsn ModuleStore](http://code.google.com/p/bsn-modulestore/) project (LGPL license). Modifying the AST is easy and you can re-script the statement afterwards.

Comment: Thank your Lucero. I'm going to use JSQLParser http://jsqlparser.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

You're using lookbehind (?<=) whereas you need lookahead (?=) assertion.

There's [more](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) on that.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you going:

```
declare
  sql_stmt varchar2(4000) := q'!SELECT * FROM myTbl WHERE columnA = 'B' AND columnB = 'C' ORDER BY columnX GROUP BY columnZ LIMIT 5!';

  where_stmt varchar2(4000) ;

begin
  where_stmt := regexp_replace(sql_stmt, '.*(WHERE.*?)ORDER BY.*', '\1');

  dbms_output.put_line(where_stmt);

end;
/
```

The *scriplet* above will output `WHERE columnA = 'B' AND columnB = 'C'`.